# How to horizontally center a link element with CSS?

Tags: css

Like the title said, how can I horizontally center the `<a>` element? Major bonus points for doing it with CSS only.

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
  align-self: center:
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.expander_link {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: hotpink;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<h4 class="center">hello</h4>
<p>
  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
</p>
<a id="link_1" href="3801" data="1" class="expander_link">center me horizontally</a>
```

Comment: You cannot use `align-self` without using `display: flex` on parent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should try like this-

```css
  .center {
  text-align: center;
  /*align-self: center;*/
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.expander_link {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: hotpink;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block; 
}
```

```html
<h4 class="center">hello</h4>
<p>
  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
</p>
<a id="link_1" href="3801" data="1" class="expander_link">center me horizontally</a>
```

Comment: display: block was the part I was missing. It even made my padding work without overlap, which I also wanted.

Answer (score 2):

To center an inline-level element, like `<a>`tag, I would suggest to wrap it into a block-level element, like `<p>` or `<div>` etc, then set `p {text-align:center;}`. See the simplest example follows:

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p><a href="#">Center me horizontally</a></p>
```

If you want extra spacing around, simply add `a {display:inline-block;}` and set `margin` and `padding` values as needed, or set it on `<p>` tag.

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
}
p a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 50px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: 1px solid aqua;
}
```

```html
<p><a href="#">Center me horizontally</a></p>
```

If you are not allowed to modify the markup, you could do the following. **Note**, the clickable area will be expanded, `padding` applies to. you might not want that. Run the demo to see.

```css
a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  outline: 1px solid aqua;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Center me horizontally</a>
```

To fix the unwanted *spacing*, you could do the `display:table` hack. It a combination of inline and block (shrink-to-fit and forces line break before/after features).

```css
a {
  display: table;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: 1px solid aqua;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Center me horizontally</a>
```

Of course, there are other ways, such as using `flexbox`, follow the other good answers to learn more about it.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
.expanded_link{
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```css
.expanded_link{
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below css in `.expander_link`

```
width: 200px;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

So your class will be like this :

```
.expander_link {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: hotpink;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

It will centralize the `<a>` horizontally, and also it is **responsive**. So no matter what the size of the page, it will always make it horizontally centered.

Here is working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kkyjm0yq/).